# Find And Delete All Empty Relationship List Objects

Tags: python, database, sqlalchemy, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

I have two objects, a Player object and a Team object.

**I want to find all the Team objects in the database without players and delete them.**

```
class Team(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'Team'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    players = db.relationship('Player', backref='team', lazy='dynamic')
```

This is what I have tried so far (unsuccessfully):

```
all_teams = Team.query.all()
for a_team in all_teams:
    if not a_team.players: # have also tried this with a .query.all() and a .all()
        db.session.delete(a_team)
db.session.commit()
```

What am I doing wrong? How should I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will likely work:

```
all_teams = Team.query.all()
for a_team in all_teams:
    if a_team.players.count() == 0
        db.session.delete(a_team)
db.session.commit()
```

But note that doing things this way is highly inefficient. If you have 100 teams the above code will have to issue 101 queries into the database to determine which teams need to be deleted. If you need to do these searches often it may be a good idea to rethink the structure of your database to make it easier to find the empty teams.

Comment: This worked. Yeah, this is just a one time thing, as I fixed the bug that was causing empty Teams, so I just wanted to clean up the empty Teams. Unfortunately, I still kept the "not" in the if statement, so all the wrong teams are deleted, lol. Stupid me. Do you know a way to revert changes?

Comment: Oh, man. Sorry! I hope you have a backup. With MySQL you may be able to revert the deletes by replaying the log up to one entry before the deletes, but that seems painful to do, you may need to investigate more as I have never done it myself.

Comment: Ah it's not too big of an issue, the database was actually still in development, we were planning on shipping within the next week or so, we may need to ship it a little later, to collect more data before we ship it. Well, at least I learned the importance of having a backup, so from now on I will have a backup. I guess it's better to lose data before shipping without a backup, than to lose it once it is shipped.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try the cascade option ?

```
players = db.relationship('Player', backref=backref("team",cascade="all,delete"), lazy='dynamic')
```

Comment: I may be misunderstanding this answer, but I only want to delete some of the teams, not all of them